# C++ noskipws manipulator affects non-formatted input function performance

Tags: c++, manipulators

I have a C# application that runs C++ executables (that were created by Visual Studio) as separate processes.  I have encountered some strange behavior involving the noskipws manipulator, *which I realize serves absolutely no purpose in the following C++ code snippet*.  ifStm is an ifstream object opened in the binary mode and ofStm is an ofstream object opened in the binary append mode.

```
ifStm >> noskipws;
for (int ch; (ch = ifStm.get()) != EOF;)
   ofStm.put((char)ch);
```

The purpose of the loop is to append every character in the input file to the output file, and it works perfectly when run directly or when run from the C# application without the noskipws statement.  However, when run from the C# application with the noskipws statement the output file ends up with random missing characters or garbage everywhere.  It appears that noskipws actually negatively affects the performance of non-formatted input functions and I'm wondering if anyone knows why.

Thanks :-)

Comment: `std::noskipws` has no effect on `istream::get()` (in fact, *all* [Unformatted Inputs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction) are implicitly noskipws). Whatever is going on, it is not in the code shown. That being said, there are better ways to make a copy of a file, and to copy chars from a `std::ifstream` to a `std::ofstream`.

Comment: On a side note, I would suggest using the `istream::get(char&)` overload instead, eg: `for (char ch; ifStm.get(ch);)`

Comment: @Remy - Thank you, and although I am aware of various other techniques, my interest at this point is in what is going on in the situation I described above.  I'm thinking that although noskipws does not affect whitespace skipping for non-formatted input functions, there's still probably some extra transparent processing involved somewhere that merely slows things down or causes race conditions of some kind when a process is run from another process :-(

Comment: there is no such processing going on. Something else is causing your issue. And the standard library is largely a header-only implementation, so the source code is largely accessible to you, just step through it with your debugger and see what is really going on.